# Monotouch and Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I have taken a look at the [github project](https://github.com/xamarin/azure-mobile-services/tree/master/sdk/xamarin/ios), but I am kind of lost. I tried to compile the solution but get errors, lots of files are missing it seems. Exactly which files/project should be added to have the azure mobile service working with a new project?

Also, given the new [changes](http://www.johanlaanstra.nl/?p=217) in mobile service, is the above going to work? Is it possible to use the portable library in monotouch?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the [Azure Mobile Services component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-mobile-services/) to your project from within Xamarin Studio (or Visual Studio if you have a Xamarin Business subscription or higher). This component includes everything needed to use AMS from your Xamarin.iOS project, and will automatically configure your project with the necessary references.